# Do-while loop executing even though condition is false

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

I need to implement both methods in this code using a do-while loop in the main method.

Every time I use the Java suggested fixes like renaming inputChar, initializing the variable, or declaring it outside of the loop; the loop still executes even if I enter "E". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Practice {
    
    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        do {
            char inputChar = getInputCharFromUser();
            String value = getValueFromChar(inputChar);
            System.out.println(value);

        } while (inputChar != ('E'));
        scanner.close();

    }
    public static char getInputCharFromUser() {
        final String CHAR_PROMPT = "Enter input char: ";
        System.out.println(CHAR_PROMPT);
        char inputChar = scanner.nextLine().charAt(0);
        return inputChar;

    }
    public static String getValueFromChar(char inputChar) {

        switch (inputChar)

        {

        case 'P':
            return "Player";
        case 'p':
            return "Player";
        case 'X':
            return "Wall";
        case 'x':
            return "Wall";
        case ' ':
            return "Empty";
        default:
            return "Invalid";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's *exactly* the goal of `do {...} while (...)`: to execute *at least once*, even if the condition is false initially: the condition is evaluated at the *end* of each iteration. If you want to evaluate the condition *before* each iteration, you need a `while (...) {...}` loop.

Comment: Instead use `while`

Comment: @BrunoReis Although your reply makes complete sense, my assignment specifically asks for a do-while loop. Also, no matter how many times I enter "E" as my inputChar, the loop still repeats. I believe the point of the assignment is to only have it execute the loop when you enter anything but "E". Thanks!

Comment: In the code you show `inputChar` is declared inside the loop body, so the `while()` can not access it and the code would not compile. However you complain about its runtime behaviour.

Comment: Where should I declare inputChar? I would like the loop to execute only when I enter anything but the letter "E". Thanks!

Comment: Before the entire loop. However you should ensure that you are not running an older variant of the program. If you are unsure, you can always add some extra text to print, or just modify the already existing message/prompt to see that the changes really appear on the screen.

Comment: @tevemadar Thanks for all your help! I solved my issue by initializing the variable, "char inputChar;" outside of the loop, and then using inputChar = getInputCharFromUser (); inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a while-loop instead of do-while-loop, you can still add an if-condition or everything else in the while-loop, so it doesnt matter.